# Angular ui bootstrap modal passing multiple parameters

Tags: javascript, django, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using an angular ui bootstrap modal for one of my applications. Currently i am calling the modal instance using the following:

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right" 
ng-click="open({{node.id}})">Add Course <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">
</span>
</button>
```

I have defined the modal as follows:

```
$scope.open = function (node) {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
        controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
        resolve: {
            detail: function() {
                return node;
            }
        }   
    });
};
```

Here the `open()` function passes the id of the node. Here node is a django item which has details like id, required etc..

My modal instance is defined as follows:

```
var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $http, $log, $modalInstance, detail) {
    $scope.subcategory = detail;
};
```

So far the modal works fine and i am able to pass the node.id to the modal. But now i want to pass even the other parameters within the node like `open({{node.required}}, {{node.id}})` etc to the modal. 
How do i modify my modal `open()` and `modalinstance()` functions to receive multiplt parameters?

Comment: It looks like you should just replace open({{node.id}}) with open(node) in your ng-click this way you can pass the whole node into your ModalInstanceCtrl.  However if you wanted to add more constructor parameters to be injected when an instance of ModalInstanceCtrl is created, you would have to add them to the resolve object.

Comment: i tried doing both. But they were not working for some reason

Comment: Post a plunker if you need help, it is very hard to assist based on the provided description.

Comment: Can you show the code that you were trying to write that wasn't working?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can add more objects to the resolve section:

```
$scope.open = function (node, node2) {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
        controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
        resolve: {
            detail: function() {
                return node;
            },
            detail2: function() {
                return node2;
            }
        }   
    });
};
```

Comment: I think you meant for "moreDetail" to be "otherStuff"

Comment: ok maybe those names were confusing, updated to better match the question.

Comment: great answer thank u.. I was trying to add them in the sameresolve function and that was the issue